# Oracle SQL - inconsistent query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an Oracle SQL query that selects a certain date range based on an employeeID (different range for every employeeID), then sums over specific performance metric numbers for each employee for that date range.  I seem to be getting inconsistent results for the same employeeID depending on how I select it. Here's my query:

```
select c.employeeID, b.assessmentDate, c.startDate, c.endDate,
sum(case when employeeProductivityMetric='15' then 1 else 0 end) as Metric1,
sum(case when employeeProductivityMetric='20' then 1 else 0 end) as Metric2
from assessmentTable b 
inner join performanceMetricTable c on b.badgeID = c.badgeID
where b.assessmentDate between c.startDate and c.endDate
group by c.employeeID, b.assessmentDate, c.startDate, c.endDate
order by c.employeeID, b.assessmentDate;
```

Note that a given employeeID can be associated with more than one badgeID.

When I select one specific employeeID (say, 2) by adding the following to the where clause:

```
where c.employeeID=2
```

I get some particular numbers for Metric1 and Metric2:

```
employeeID  assessmentDate  startDate   endDate    Metric1  Metric2
2           02-Jul-15       01-Jul-15   31-Jul-15  4        5
```

however, when I do

```
where c.employeeID between 1 and 3
```

I get different numbers for employee 2, something like:

```
employeeID  assessmentDate   startDate  endDate    Metric1  Metric2
2           02-Jul-15        01-Jul-15  31-Jul-15  3        0
```

Does anyone know why that would be the case?  Is there something wrong with my query design?

Thank you for any pointers!

Natalia

Comment: Is it possible that a `badgeID` is linked to several `employeeID`s?

Comment: You are grouping by `employeeId`.  I don't see how a filter condition on that column would affect the results within a row for a given value.

Answer (score 0):

You may debug this type of situations by retrieving the detailed records:

Try to compare the following queries

```
-- matched records for employeeID=2
select c.employeeID, c.badgeID, b.assessmentDate, c.startDate, c.endDate,
employeeProductivityMetric
from assessmentTable b 
inner join performanceMetricTable c on b.badgeID = c.badgeID
where b.assessmentDate between c.startDate and c.endDate
      and c.employeeID=2
order by c.employeeID, c.badgeID, b.assessmentDate;
```

and

```
-- matched records for employeeID between 1 and 3
select c.employeeID, c.badgeID, b.assessmentDate, c.startDate, c.endDate,
employeeProductivityMetric
from assessmentTable b 
inner join performanceMetricTable c on b.badgeID = c.badgeID
where b.assessmentDate between c.startDate and c.endDate
      and c.employeeID between 1 and 3
order by c.employeeID, c.badgeID, b.assessmentDate
```

Most probably, you'll notice a difference in the `badgeIds` returned by each query.